# advance search using checkbox in php

Tags: php

I can not make a search using this check boxes. When I run the code (check), nothing happens. I have to check it for make an advance search and it will select data from database.

My HTMLcode:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="fac1" value="checked"/>AIRCOND</td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="fac2" value="checked"/>FAN</td>
```

My PHP code:

```
$fac1=isset($_POST["fac1"]);
$fac2=isset($_POST["fac2"]);

$qry = "SELECT * FROM homestay WHERE ";
 if(isset($_POST['fac1']) && $_POST['fac1'] == 'checked')
 {
        $fac1 = true;
 }
 if(isset($_POST['fac2']) && $_POST['fac2'] == 'checked')
 {
        $fac2 = true;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = isset($_POST['fac1']) ? $_POST['fac1'] : (isset($_POST['fac2']) ? $_POST['fac2'] : '');
```

OR

```
if(isset($_POST['fac1']) && $_POST['fac1'] == 'checked')
{
    $string = $fac1;
}
if(isset($_POST['fac1']) && $_POST['fac2'] == 'checked')
{
    $string = $fac2;
}
```

Pass your string variable in `query`:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM homestay WHERE $string = 'true'";
```

Comment: I've tried. No kind of error. but when click the checkbox, it will say is not in the database. in this form i also use for search by textfield and drop down list. for both option it can use. but for checkbox it seem cannot find.

Comment: thanks Ronak Patel for helping. it done already. i got it now :)

Answer (score 0):

Doing it like as Ronak suggested would result in a way too long code for multiple search options. Not counting that you have to save every option checked next time you load the page with one option checked.
You could simplify this with ajax, so that it would display the results in your div for example.

first make a form:

```
<form id="searchOptions">
 <td><input type="checkbox" name="fac1" value="checked"/>AIRCOND</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" name="fac2" value="checked"/>FAN</td>
</form>
```

Then put the script in header:

```
<script>
function submitSearchForm() {
    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'search.php', data:$('#searchOptions').serialize();?>, success: function(response) {
            $('#resultDisplay').innerHTML = response;
            }});
    return false;
}
</script>
```

Notice:

You will also need jquery.min in header

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks Caddaile for helping. it done already. i got it now :)